# Forcing remote sound on Windows 7 Remote Desktop: possible?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, audio

I have a very quiet, efficient server that mainly serves files all day, which I control over RDP. The regular remote desktop client allows one to play sound locally (on the connecting computer/device).
I would like to be able to connect to the server from my Nokia N900 to play music streams **on** the server, which is connected to a stereo system, but the N900 remote desktop client doesn't have a setting to control sound playback and therefore "steals" the audio output from the server.

So my question is this: is there a way to *force* local (on the server) audio playback on my server *during* an RDP session?
(Switching to VNC or similar is something I'd like to avoid for now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RDP protocol allows sound to be muted/local/remote whilst VNC just pulls the screen to you.

You have two choices -

1. Find an alternate RDP client that fully supports the protocol, allowing you to leave sound at the machine.
2. Install VNC or an alternate remote application.

Comment: Although I'm worried that your answer is the only correct one, I'll hold out on accepting it for a little while. To my knowledge another RDP client is not available...

Comment: After looking around for a little bit, I found quite a decent VNC client for my N900: [Presence VNC](http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=59570). VNC it is. Thanks.